# How to disable network-connectivity-check on linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, dns, wireshark

(Virtualbox OS: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa)

I am trying to disable the network-connectivity-check on Linux Mint. 
[This website](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/disable-network-connectivity-checking-ubuntu-17-10) shows how to disable it in the GUI for Ubuntu 17.10.
Unfortunately in Mint the path 
`Settings > Privacy > Turn off "network connectivity checking"`
does not exist.
According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080850) the GUI just changes a line entry in the file `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-intern.conf` to false:

```
[connectivity] 
.set.enabled=false
```

By using `cat` I saw that these two lines didn't even exist, therefore I inserted them and tried the following procedure again:

```
1. network-tray-icon > Wired_connection_1 > Disconnect
2. wireshark start packet capturing for interface "enp0s3"
3. network-tray-icon > Wired_connection_1 > Connect
4. wireshark stop packet capturing
```

By applying the display-filter `(dns.qry.name == "connectivity-check.ubuntu.com")`, inside wireshark, there are exactly 100 DNS-queries and their corresponding responses.
So the insertion of those two lines didn't work.

I also did overwrite the following file as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094558):

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf
```

Still exact 100 DNS-messages.

How do I disable the network-connectivity-check on Linux Mint, 
by using the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [connectivity section in gnome docs](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html):

> Note that your distribution might set `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter` to strict filtering. That works badly with per-device connectivity checking, which uses SO_BINDDEVICE to send requests on all devices. **A strict `rp_filter` setting will reject any response and the connectivity check on all but the best route will fail**.

command lines (as root):

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.<NET_INTERFACE_HERE>.rp_filter=0
sysctl -p
```

You can also remove the package `network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu`:

```
apt purge network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu
```